# Multiple copies of a pytest fixture

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

Let's say I have a simple fixture like the following (using pytest-django, but it applies to pytest as well):

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_thing(request, db):
    thing = MyModel.objects.create()
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: thing.delete())
    return thing
```

This works great when my tests need a single instance of MyModel. But what about if I need two (or three or four)? I want each instance to be distinct, but to be set up in the same way.

I could copy/paste the code and rename the fixture function, but that seems inelegant.

Similarly, I have tried:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_thing_1(my_thing):
    return my_thing

@pytest.fixture
def my_thing_2(my_thing):
    return my_thing
```

However, each of these appears to return the same instance of MyModel.

Is there a way to do what I want using pytest's built-in functionality? Alternately, I could move the setup/teardown of my fixture out into helper functions so I'm not duplicating too much code.

Or am I going about this whole thing the wrong way?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

My approach would probably to create a fixture which can generate your objects:

```
@pytest.fixture
def thing(request, db):
    class ThingFactory(object):
        def get(self):
            thing = MyModel.objects.create()
            request.addfinalizer(thing.delete)
            return thing
    return ThingFactory()

def test_thing(thing):
    thing1 = thing.get()
    thing2 = thing.get()
```

Obviously you can make `.get()` take an argument etc.

(PS: Also note there's no need for the lambda in the finalizer)

Comment: 1) Good call on not needing lambda in the finalizer. 2) I like your approach. I'm actually using Factory Boy to create these models, so I think ideally I wouldn't even need to create factory fixtures for each model. But I'm having trouble subclassing ModelFactory to recursively add finalizers for SubFactories, so I think I'll use your approach as a stop gap. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, the only reason I was using finalizers was because pytest-django wasn't cleaning the database in between tests because it does not support multiple databases (see also https://github.com/pelme/pytest_django/issues/76). For the type of problem I describe above, I wholeheartedly recommend using FactoryBoy with pytest-django.

Comment: How do you define tear-down logic in this case? In particular, I want to be sure that the tear down happens even if the test fails/raises an exception.

Comment: @ingomueller.net Use `with` [contextlib.ExitStack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=exitstack#contextlib.ExitStack) `as stack`, yield the factory, have `.get()` register the destructor with `stack.callback()`

Comment: @clacke: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Nice pattern also for other situations... thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I'm arriving at this question very late... but, using a parametrized fixture and simply returning the fixture you want to duplicate seems to work too.

```
import pytest
import random

@pytest.fixture
def name():
    return random.randint(0, 10)


@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 1])
def parametrized_name(request, name):
    return name


def test_something(parametrized_name):
    print "Testing with name: " + str(parametrized_name)
```

If you run the above test, you get 2 different "name" fixtures

```
$ pytest -s blah.py
============================================= test session starts ==============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/bsquizza/repos/blah/tests, inifile:
collected 2 items                                                                                              

blah.py Testing with name: 7
.Testing with name: 10
.                                                                                               [100%]

=========================================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================================
```

Comment: This doesn't help - the question is about getting two different instances within the same test - what you have here generates two different tests.